# Looping a Bash in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg

Any idea how to make a .Sh file loop? Im using a stream  code with FFMPEG and when the source goes down the .sh Closes and takes me offline anyway to have on error the .sh bash keep trying the code over and over until the source comes back on instead of just closing and having to be Manually restarted each time? i know on windows this is easy with adding loop code :loop but this does not seem to work on linux im new to linux and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
    ffmpeg -re -i "input" output.mp4
done
```

`:` is a built-in no-operation command that always succeeds, to be used as a placeholder when you need a command like this.

Comment: do i add that to my current .sh?

Comment: Your current `.sh` is `/path/to/script.sh`. This will keep running it in a loop when it exits.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -re -i "input" -f flv output.mp4 is my current code so i would do
while :; do
    /path/to/script.sh
done
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -re -i "input" -f flv output.mp4 ?

Comment: ohh ok so i make loop.sh with 
while :; do
    /path/to/script.sh
done

Comment: i made loop1.sh with 
while :; do
    /root/stream.sh
done
then saved it and ran nano bash loop1.sh .

Comment: Why are you using `nano` there? That's an editor, it has nothing to do with running scripts.

Comment: omgg it works thanks so much :D sorry for my blondness xD u saved my weblife!!!

Comment: @Barmar - it might be better with `while ffmpeg ...; do :; done` - this makes it much easier to break the loop.

Comment: @AFH I don't know the circumstances under which `ffmpeg` exits, and whether they govern whether it should be restarted.

Comment: @Barmar - Valid point, and I've just checked that `Ctrl-C` breaks the loop in either case, as it gets passed to the shell as well as to `ffmpeg`, but I thought that the questioner should be made aware of the other possibility, so that he will consider how the loop should be broken.

Comment: its A 24/7 stream i don't plan to stop the loop but if  ineed to ill just reboot the server and rerun the .sh  to restart it